# Edit the nodes in a binary tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

Okay. I have a binary tree, and this is what I want to do with it:

For each node in original tree:
 If it's not a leaf, replace it with a leaf node.
 Do a calculation on the original tree updated with the removed branch.
 Revert the node back to how it was (so now the tree is the same as at the beginning).

The problem is this: I am traversing the tree using a stack.  If I change the stack.pop() node to a leaf, this does NOT remove any branches in the original tree.  It's the same reasoning behind why you can do:

```
int x=1
int y=x
y++
```

And x still equals 1.  There's a technical term for this but I forgot it.

So how can I edit the nodes in an original tree and still traverse it?

This is basically what I'm doing to traverse the tree right now:

```
public void iterativePreorder(Node root) {
        Stack nodes = new Stack();
        nodes.push(root);

        Node currentNode;

        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
                currentNode = nodes.pop();
                Node right = currentNode.right();
                if (right != null) {
                        nodes.push(right);
                }
                Node left = currentNode.left();
                if (left != null) {
                        nodes.push(left);      
                }
                //This is where you do operations on the currentNode
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your question, for every `Node` you want to calculate something about the tree as if that node was a leaf.

To do this there is no reason to actually make that node a leaf and then reattach it. Instead, your logic can simply remember which node to treat as a leaf for each computation.

Traverse the tree, and for each `Node`, let's call it `outerCurrentNode`, once again traverse the tree doing your calculation - but now for each `Node`, let's call it `innerCurrentNode`, test to see if `outerCurrentNode == innerCurrentNode`. If the test returns `true`, treat that `innerCurrentNode` as if it's a leaf, ignoring its children.

**EDIT:** Here's a mock up of what I'm suggesting (untested):

```
//entry point - called from directing code
public void iterativePreorder(Node root) {
   iterativePreorderKernel(root, root);
}

//recursive method - keeps track of root in addition to current Node
private void iterativePreorderKernel(Node root, Node current) {

    if (current.left() != null) {
        iterativePreorderKernel(root, current.left());
    }
    if (current.right() != null) {
        iterativePreorderKernel(root, current.right());
    }

    //for each Node in the tree, do calculations on the entire tree, pretending
    //the current Node is a leaf
    doCalculation(root, current);
}

//calculation method (also recursive) - takes a current Node, plus
//the Node to treat as a leaf
public void doCalculation(Node innerCurrent, Node pretendLeaf) {

   //do calculation with inner current node

   if (innerCurrent != pretendLeaf) {
      if (innerCurrent.left() != null) {
         doCalculation(innerCurrent.left(), pretendLeaf);
      }
      if (innerCurrent.right() != null) {
         doCalculation(innerCurrent.right(), pretendLeaf);
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using recursion instead of a `Stack`, but either will work. `iterativePreorder()` does a traversal, calling `doCalculation()` for each `Node`, passing it in along with the root (to keep track of the entire tree). That method then does its own traversal, doing your calculation, but stopping short when it reaches the specially marked `Node`.

Comment: I don't know if it will be feasible to do that.  After I change the node to a leaf, I need to pass the entire tree to another method, and it seems very difficult to just treat the node as a leaf when I do that.  Then I reattach the children (I was doing this by storing currentNode in a temp variable, removing the children, and then setting currentNode equal to the temp variable).  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @smcg - It shouldn't matter. Pass a reference to the current node into whatever method is doing the inner traversal/calculation, and it can do the same check. Let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: @smcg - Also, just wondering why you're using a `Stack` instead of recursion to traverse?

Comment: Um, I'm using a stack because it just seemed like the easiest way to do it. I could try with recursion.

Comment: I have another problem which may or may not be related to this one... if I check the size of the tree at "root right" before the while loop, it gives the proper size... but if I check the size of "root" at the top of the while loop, it says the size is 1 (except on the first iteration).  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: There isn't a huge difference, they're both depth first for example. Was just curious. So will passing the current node to the calculation work?

Comment: RE: size, I'm not sure. Does your example show the real code or is it simplified?

Comment: Example shows simplified code.  Passing the current node wouldn't really work because I need to pass the entire tree (with the missing branch).  This is for a reduced error post-pruning algorithm for a machine learning program using decision trees.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. Think about what it means to "pass the entire tree" - you just pass the root node, from which you can traverse the tree. Plus, you pass the current node, which tells the traversal when to pretend it's reached a dead end. If it's any more complicated then I'm missing a part of the picture here.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. I was trying to avoid that because that function (the error calculator) is used for other things, but I guess I can just copy+paste and add the parameter for the new method. Text is cheap, at least.

Comment: Updated my answer with a conceptual example. Hope this helps.